# Is it necessary to (re?) use "var" here?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I am running SonarQube against an old application. It's flagging something in JavaScript (not TypeScript or any fancy modern thing, just plain old JavaScript) that I think is a false positive, but I'm not one hundred percent sure. It looks like this minimal example:

```
var foo=null;
var bar=["a","b","c","foobar"]
for(var i=0; i<bar.length; i++) {
    if(bar[i] == "foobar") {
        foo = i;
    }
}
```

And it's flagging on the line foo = i; saying that we should use "var" to declare foo, but you can see that foo was declared previously. Is this some weird JavaScript scope thing, do I need to use var again? Or can I just mark this as a false positive and move on?

(The actual application is working as expected, but we are being asked to read and [somehow] address any SonarQube findings.)

Here is another minimal example that you may find more plausible...it is flagging on many similar examples (remember this application is old, and we're not really beautifying it, actually the front end *at least* is on the chopping block to be completely rewritten in the near future) and many of them really are simple like this:

```
var isFoobar=false;
var bar=["foo","foobar"];
for(var i=0; i<bar.length; i++) {
    if(bar[i] == "foobar") {
        isFoobar = true;
    }
    // if baz, set isBaz variable
    // if buzz, set isBuzz variable
    // etc. etc. for many more
}
// do something with isFoobar, isBaz, isBuzz, etc., down here
```

As crazy as this looks, things like "indexOf" just weren't around when this was written (originally supporting IE 8 or earlier and never upgraded since, just continuing to run in IE in "legacy mode").

Comment: There is no point in adding `var` to the assignment to `foo`. If that's really what the code looks like, the tool is wrong.

Comment: IMHO, `var foo = -1;` is more consistent than `var foo = null;`. Perhaps the tool is suggesting to redeclare the variable because the data type changed.

Comment: In fact, if you add `var` there, other tools like `eslint` will warn you that you're redeclaring the variable.

Comment: Something should warn you that the entire code could be replaced with `foo = bar.lastIndexOf("foobar");`

Comment: @Barmar except that in case nothing is found `foo` will be `-1` instead of `null`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I realize that, it's a simple extra check.

Comment: All of this said, my money would be on this toy example not reflecting the actual code correctly. I doubt that this is truly a false positive, it seems too crazy.

Comment: The linter is probably expecting you to scope your variables to where they are accessed. Your code snippet does not access `foo` outside of the `if` block and its a common practice to "scope" variables close to their usage (ignoring the fact that Javascript hoists `var` variables). If you access the `foo` variable in some way after the loop does the finding go away?

Comment: I have tried to address comments and added a second example so you can see that it is not purely crazy code, just very old and clunky.

Answer (score 0):

It's a false positive - you could clean up things with:

```
var foo = ["a","b","c","foobar"].lastIndexOf("foobar");
foo = foo < 0 ? null : foo;
```